# Openshift failed to pull image "x509 certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, openshift

My deployment yaml file has 2 images;

1) redis:alpine it works fine

2) Openshift pulls image from my own harbor registry

My harbor registry has ssl **(not self sign)** certificate.

I can login to my harbor registry, pull, push images as a container without getting an error.

But openshift has problem to pull my image from my harbor registry.

`oc describe pod <mypodname>`
prints this error

```
Failed to pull image <myregistry.net<myrepo><myimage><mytag>> : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = pinging container registry myregistry.net: Get "https://<myregistry>.net/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have ca.crt under /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry

I tried https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/cicd/builds/setting-up-trusted-ca.html#configmap-adding-ca_setting-up-trusted-ca this solution, did not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added new image registry in your pull-secret.json ?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the above doc, it should work.

```
$ oc patch proxies.config.openshift.io/cluster --type=merge -p '{"spec":{"trustedCA":{"name":"user-ca-bundle"}}}'
$ oc -n openshift-config create configmap user-ca-bundle --from-file=ca-bundle.crt=xxx/rootCA.pem
```